# How to login OBIEE Server credentials from perl script

Tags: perl, obiee

I need to create a procees which generates a txt file from the reports. I need to login into OBiee Bussiness Intelignce, give the credentails and generate a report with respective column names and load the data in to text file. I don't know OBIEE or Perl. I Googled and found some related URL

```
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/catalog_manager
```

I need to login in to Obiee Tool with following credential using Perl script. How can I login into server using Perl?

What I have tried so far is:

```
use strict;

use warnings;
```

Error:

> Missing or bad "-output file"

Comment: Read the error message: The first part means that you defined `$request_name` twice: remove one of the two `my` definitions or merge them into one. It also says that `$request_column` is not defined but used in `@call`. Also, a scalar variable (one that starts with a `$`) may hold only a single string (not two, as in "Column" "Created Time"). I suggest you start off with something simple, like try to get only one column. If this works, you can extend your request.

Comment: Hi, YEs I found that error and changed to request_Column sclar variable. but still I found the errors throwing me, please check the updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what this is or what it does, but from the doc at the URL you found, it appears like the API allows a query like so:

```
catalogmanager -online http://localhost:9704/analytics/saw.dll
-login Administrator -pwd Administrator
-cmd report -of c:\output.csv -delimiter \",\"
-type Requests \"Request Name\" \"Request Criteria Column\"
```

If I read this correctly, then you should provide in this call:

- The correct server, i.e., replace `localhost` with your hostname if the catalogmanager or whatever is not running on the local machine
- The username and password as arguments to `-login` and `-pwd`
- An output file name as argument to `-of` (it will probably be a CSV file)
- And some sort of request structure that should be provided in place of "Request Name" and "Request Criteria Column"

And you would use this in Perl in a script like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# change this to your URL
my $address        = 'http://localhost:9704/analytics/saw.dll';
my $username       = 'ADMIN';  # change this to your username
my $pwd            = 'PASSWORD';  # change this to your password
my $outputfile     = 'PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE';  # change this to your output file
my $delimiter      = ',';
my $request_name   = 'REQUEST_NAME';  # adjust this
my $request_column = 'REQUEST_COLUMN';  # and this

my @call = qq( catalogmanager -online $address -login $username 
    -pwd $password -cmd report -of $outputfile -delimiter $delimiter 
    -type Requests $request_name $request_column );

# system() returns true if the call was not successful,
# we can make use of this and let the program die if something went wrong
system(@call) and die("Could not exec @call: $!\n");
```

And it should hopefully write an output file to the path you specified. This file you can parse, but that is a different matter.

Comment: Hi How can i access to columns of -type. i have multiple columns which i need to load. Thank You so much for the help

Comment: Hi mpe, with your code, I have modified it and run the file, but its not executing the catalogmanager -online $address -login $username 
    -pwd $password -cmd report -of $outputfile -delimiter $delimiter 
    -type Requests $request_name $request_column it throwing some errors

Comment: As I said, I know next to nothing about this program and its API, I was just figuring this from the page you linked to. About the columns: You probably need to provide these in `$request_column`. About "some errors": Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi mpe, please check the post I have updated my complete file and error where I am getting.

Comment: My typo: `qw()` does not do variable interpolation.

Comment: Can you please suggest me, what can i do to overcome the above error.I am trying this from days..

Comment: I tried even wit qq(), I am getting error at column names, how can i pass column names from request_name and request_column

Comment: Hi Mpe, I am able to generate Reports from the above code, but I cannot able to load that data in to CSV file, It saying missing or bad "-output file"

Comment: Maybe the option is called `-output` instead of `-of` like it said on the page.